# Display django form initial without brackets

Tags: django

I have a object from query

```
object_query = werknemer_object_query = 
user.objects.filter(profile__werkgevers_id=werkgeversId)
```

Created f-string based on query

```
result = [
    f"{item.first_name} {item.last_name}"
    for item in werknemer_object_query
    if item.pk == int(werknemer_get)]
```

---> this creates a list

form initial with created f-string

```
form.initial = {"test": f"{result} is bla bla"
```

In html page when i call this field test, its being displayed as `["result"]` with brackets.

How can i get instead of `["result"]` just result in the f-string.

Comment: results is an array and not string, so result is string representation of an array,

Comment: i understand, but how can i get the string representation of ["result"] in the form.initial

Comment: What exactly you are getting it is unclear

Comment: what about: `{% for item in form.test %} {{ item }} {% endfor %}`.?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join

Comment: Sorry no, i was not complete (i edited the code). Result is a part of a f string form.initial = {"test": f"{result} is bla bla".

Comment: Show us the context, where you build result, and how you pass it to initialize form